# Need some help in searching a text from page in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am searching a text from page. My function is working fine but my Problem is that on clicking a search button it search first .But when user click again search button  it should go to next search but it is not going. But on clicking the next it is going to next.I need same functionality on next and search button. Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/wjLmx/28/

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches, selector = selector || "#realTimeContents";
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');

            $span = $('#realTimeContents span');
            $span.replaceWith($span.html());

            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');

            $(selector).html(txt);

            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

            var i = 0;
                $('.searchButtonClickText_h').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;
                alert("OO")
                if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });

            $('.next_h').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;

                if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });
            $('.previous_h').off('click').on('click', function () {

                i--;

                if (i < 0) i = $('.match').length - 1;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });




            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$(document).on('click', '.searchButtonClickText_h', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.textSearchvalue_h').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }


});
```

I need user go to next when user click the search button as it is going in next button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/umodoy/7) and [**AutoSearch DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/umodoy/11)

Here is the code -

```
var searchIndex = -1;
var searchTermOld ='';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()===''){
      var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
      $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    });
  }
  searchIndex = -1;
  $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  searchTermOld = $(this).val();
});
  $('.searchbox').on('keyup',function(){

    var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
    if($(this).val()===''){
       $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    });
   }
   if($(this).val() !== searchTermOld){
       $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    });
       searchIndex = -1;
       $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");                              
   }
});
  $('.search').on('click',function(){
    if(searchIndex == -1){
      var searchTerm = $('.searchbox').val();
      searchAndHighlight(searchTerm);
  }
  else searchNext();
  if($('.match').length >1){
      $('.searchNext').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
  $('.searchNext').on('click',searchNext);

  $('.searchPrev').on('click',searchPrev);
});

function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
        });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
            $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

function searchNext(){
  searchIndex++;
  if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) searchIndex = 0;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}

function searchPrev(){
  searchIndex--;
  if (searchIndex < 0) searchIndex = $('.match').length - 1;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
```

Comment: is this possible to disable next or previous button .till search button not selected ..? it mean if user should select first time search then next and previous are disable.After first time it should select next and previous ..

Comment: code is running perfectly ..!! one more issue .search for rohit.then press search.remove text from text field then press (next , previous) it is working .but i think it should not work when there is no text in  field..

Comment: if there is  no text i think they are disable ? may i right ?

Comment: I more issue it is not scrolling when there is lot of data .But in my example it is scrolling..:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33893/discussion-between-rohit-agrawal-and-rohit)

Comment: if there is no match than there should be an alert ..?

Comment: you can do at-least that no?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
if(highlighted span != search input) {

    Search again

}else{

    Go to next, trigger click on `.next_h`

}
```